# ASP.NET MVC Url.Action removes controller and anction name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello i have admin area in my project. AreaRegistration is default

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName => "Admin";

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

When i use `Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard")` it returns `/admin`, but i want to get path like `admin/{controller}` so it must be `/admin/dashboard`. But when users navigate to `/admin` it needs to redirect to `/admin/dashboard`

So i need that

1) `Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard")` will return `/admin/dashboard`

2)user navigation to `/admin` will redirect him to `/admin/dashboard`

Is there way to do this with mvc routing?

Comment: If you only have a few controllers in that area, then remove the default one and add specific entries for each one.

Answer (score 0):

As always after posting in SO solution found myself

The solution is using `Url.RouteUrl("Admin_Dashboard")` and route

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_Dashboard",
            "admin/dashboard",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```